# Access violation on unusual program termination (C++)

Tags: c++, access-violation

The following minimum code examples runs fine when it is terminated normally (by pressing enter):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class SingletonLogClass
{

private:

    SingletonLogClass() {}

public:

    ~SingletonLogClass()
    {
        LogMessage("~SingletonLogClass()");
    }

    static SingletonLogClass& getInstance(void)
    {
        static SingletonLogClass inst;
        return inst;
    }

    void LogMessage(string msg)
    {
        //printf("%s\n", msg.c_str());
        cout << msg << endl;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SingletonLogClass::getInstance().LogMessage("This is a message");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

When I terminate the program by closing the console window it depends on the implementation of the `LogMessage` function. If it's implemented using `printf` everything is fine. But when it's implemented using `cout` I get an access violation.

Can someone explain this?
What exactly happens when the program is terminated by closing the console window?
Why does it work with `printf` but not with `cout`?

I'm working with VC++ 2010.

Comment: Getting what you ask for, personally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cout` is a global object. Your singleton instance (defined as static in the `getInstance` static member function) is also a global object.

In C++, you cannot have control over the order of construction, neither destruction of global objects. As such, it is possible that the `cout` object is destructed before your `SingletonLogClass` is. As the destructor of your `SingletonLogClass` logs something, it cannot use anymore `cout` (whereas `printf` is fine).

The difference in behaviour when the program is terminated normally (pressing enter) and thus exiting the `main` function, and when the program is terminated abruptly by closing the shell comes from the order of destruction of globals. *You cannot have control over the order of destruction of global objects.*

Comment: @Didier Trosset: My +1, that is spot on.

Comment: Ok this makes sense so far. But why does it work when the program is terminated normally? Is there a different mechanism involved or is it pure luck that in this case my `SingletonLogClass` is destroyed first?

Comment: How the singleton instance a global object?

Comment: @Nawaz: The singleton instance is a `function local` `static` object. As such it lies in the global data area (opposed to stack and heap).

Comment: @Didier: But how is it global instance? If an object's duration is the duration of the program doesn't mean its global object.

Comment: @Nawaz: Object duration is not the duration of the program: it is created only upon the first call to this function. As the oject is neither on the stack, nor in the heap, it is in the global data space.

Comment: @Didier: What do you mean by "global data space"? The fact is that the singleton instance is not a global instance, its local to the function but it has **static storage duration** and that makes it retains its value till the program ends. IF it were a global variable, then it would have been accessible from outside the function as well.

Comment: @Nawaz: global data space, means that this instance is stored in the same memory area as global variables (not in heap, not in stack, but in global data memory space). Being stored the same way the global variable are, it also has to share their destruction order mechanism, on which C++ offers no control. (I don't mean anything about accessibility from a single function, or globally from everywhere.)

Comment: @Didier: Where its stored is implementation detail, the language specification doesn't impose any such rule which you're talking about. The point is that saying the static variable declared inside a function is a global instance is wrong, since it is not. Global variables has specific meaning in C++ which has nothing to do with the region in the memory where its stored.